# jQuery datepicker not working on MVC4 application

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

I am trying to introuduce jQuery datepicker to my MVC4 application but I cannot seem to get the click event to fire the datepicker widget. At http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ they give a simple example of how to implement this and when I try locally it works as expected but on MVC4 application nothing:

My code is as follows:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#expirydate').datepicker();
  });
</script>

<div class="nine columns bottom20">
  <div class="row">
     <h3>New Course details</h3>

      @using(Html.BeginForm("NewCourse","Admin",FormMethod.Post))
      {
        <div class="row">
          <div class="twelve columns" style="width:590px;">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="six columns">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /><br />
              </div>
              <div class="six columns">
                <label for="author">Author:</label>
                <input type="text" id="author" name="author" /><br />
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="twelve columns" style="width:590px; margin-left:5px;">
                  <label for="description">Description:</label>
                  <input type="text" id="description" name="description" /><br />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="twelve columns" style="width:590px;">
              <div class="row">                    
                <div class="six columns">
                  <label for="participationpoints">Participation Points:</label>
                  <input type="text" id="participationpoints" name="participationpoints" /><br />
                </div>
                <div class="six columns">
                  <label for="expirydate">Expiry Date:</label>
                  <input type="text" id="expirydate" name="expirydate" /><br />
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>



              <div class="row">
                <div class="six columns">
                  <input type="hidden" id="uploaddate" name="uploaddate" /><br />
                </div>  
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>            
          <div class="twelve columns"> 
          <input id="CourseSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit button" class="medium button bottom20"style="margin-left:210px; margin-top:-50px;" />
          </div> 
      }
    </div>   
  </div>
```

Any ideas what is going on here?

Other scripts in the layout are as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/foundation.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr.foundation.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/plugins/slider-revolution/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/plugins/slider-revolution/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.3-packed.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/plugins/titan/js/jquery.titanlighbox.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/plugins/titan/js/prettify.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/meta-app-head.js")"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/meta-app.js")"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/filedrag.js")"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/footable.js")"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/footable.sortable.js")"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/footable.filter.js.js")"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/footable.paginate.js")"></script>
```

And my bundle config is as follows:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.js",
                    "~/Scripts/foundation.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr.foundation.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.3-packed.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js",
                    "~/plugins/slider-revolution/jquery.thempunch.plugins.min.js",
                    "~/plugins/slider-revolution/jquery.thempunch.revolution.min.js",
                    "~/plugins/flexislider/jquery.flexslider.js",
                    "~/plugins/camera/scripts/camera.min.js",
                    "~/plugins/camera/scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js",
                    "~/plugins/camera/scripts/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js",
                    "~/plugins/titan/js/jquery.titanlighbox.js",
                    "~/plugins/titan/js/prettify.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/footable.js",
                    "~/Scripts/footable.sortable.js",
                    "~/Scripts/footable.filter.js",
                    "~/Scripts/footable.paginate.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
```

Comment: are you sure that jquery ui is loading?

Comment: I had it included in my bundle config and was worried that this was not being called so i have specifically specified it in the html to point to the folder in which it is contained

Comment: Are you including any other scripts on your layout?

Comment: yes I have several other scripts called on the layout.

Comment: Could you show those as well?  Just curious if there may be a conflict.

Comment: Looks like you are rending jQuery twice, that could cause an issue.

Comment: I removed the first call to jquery in the layouts and it now seems to be working thanks for your help greatly appreciated asymptoticFault :)

Comment: Sweet I'll post that as an answer if you'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rending jQuery twice, once in your layout and again on your view.  This could be causing the issue you are seeing.

Comment: Sorry I posted an edit during some changes, the id of the input is expirydate and this is why i used $('#expirydate').datepicker();

Comment: Ah ok, well that takes care of that problem then.  So you are having the issue even now with the correction?

Comment: Yes issue remains, I was changing to datepicker as this was tag used in example which i noticed tied in with id of the form control, i tried this locally with expirydate as id of field and no problems but in mvc4 app nothing is shown

Comment: Check to make sure the jQuery files are being sent to the browser.  Did you check for javascript errors in the debugger of whatever browser you are using?  Are the jQuery files you're including here the same version as the ones you are using "locally"?  What do you mean by locally exactly?  You should be running the MVC application locally as well unless you are deploying it to a server and that is where you are having the issue.

Comment: Sorry when I say locally I mean creating a simple html file and included in this simple html file links to the same jquery files on the desktop

Comment: Oh ok, I figured that's maybe what you meant but just wanted to be sure.  How about the other questions I asked?

Comment: Cant see any errors using firefox anyway, yes they are same javascripts versions as used locally

Answer (score 0):

the correct code:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
```

check your css file jquery-ui.

Selector in jquery

`#`= ID

`.` = class

by some attribute

```
$('a[href=www.google.com]')
```

Comment: sorry was mistake in the post

Comment: I am now able to successfully choose an date and the textbox is being populated in the format MM/DD/YYYY but my date format is DD/MM/YYYY so when I chose 1st august (08/08/2013) no problem it works but if i choose 28th (08/28/2013) then I get a date exception error. Can I change the culture of the textbox using jQuery so that it posts in the format i am expecting on selection/